# Problems with RAID1 array being recognised

Tags: raid, vmware-esxi, dell, bios, virtual-disk

I have put a new RAID card (UCS-51) into my Dell Precision T5400.

I have connected this to 2 x 1TB SATA disks.

I have configured a mirror array in the RAID bios.

The array shows when I boot computer up.

Sadly every OS I try and install (Win7 & ESXi) says there is no storage devices found.

Can anyone assist? Pics below...

[image: RAID BIOS]

[image: ARRAY]

[image: ARRAY]

[image: BOOT SCREEN]

[image: OS INSTALL ERROR]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about this controller particular, but it seems that it requires OS Support in order to function (See http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/storage/RAID/SAS5iR/en/UG/HTML/index.htm)

Looks like you need to use a different controller, since ESXi doesn't recognize it.

Comment: I took this RAID card out of an older 32 bit Dell server which I had running ESXi server on. This makes me think that OS support is not required. Anyone for further advice? Thanks Paul